# Register a Component with IServiceCollection

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to build my NotificationLibrary so it feels like a real .NET Core component.

This is what I want in my Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddNotificationLibrary(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigSectionName = "notificationSetup";
    });
}
```

So the next steps should be to configure the NotificationLibrary with the configuration from appsetting.json and register it in DI.

This is what I have so fare

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
public static class NotificationLibraryFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddNotificationLibrary(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<NotificationLibraryOptions> configure)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        if (configure != null)
        {
            services.Configure(configure);
        }

        services.AddScoped<IMailFactory, MailFactory>(provider =>
        {
            var mailFactory = new MailFactory();
            var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            //var setup = configuration. /* How to I get the section name? */
            var config = new NotificationSetup();
            mailFactory.Configure(config);

            return mailFactory;
        });
        return services;
    }
}
```

}

I am stocked getting the config section name, and I don't understand what services.Configure(configure); are doing.

I want to create a configration poco object and add it as a singleton to the service collection. Next step would be to call mailFactory.Configure(config); and return the mailFactory object.

I am close, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the options registered with the service collection

```
public static IServiceCollection AddNotificationLibrary(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<NotificationLibraryOptions> configure) {
    if (services == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    if (configure != null) {
        services.Configure(configure);
    }

    services.AddScoped<IMailFactory, MailFactory>(provider => {
         /* How to I get the section name? */
        IOptions<NotificationLibraryOptions> options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<NotificationLibraryOptions>>();
        string sectionName = options.Value.ConfigSectionName;
        
        var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        NotificationSetup config = configuration.GetSection(sectionName).Get<NotificationSetup>();
        
        MailFactory mailFactory = new MailFactory();            
        mailFactory.Configure(config);
        return mailFactory;
    });
    return services;
}
```

Comment: So services.Configure(configure); make this line possible provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<NotificationLibraryOptions>>();

Comment: @MartinAndersen Yes. That is part of the Options pattern in .net core.